# How to remove complete line from the string on basis of generic type using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code where I tried to remove the complete line if there is one argument and whose value is `Window: String`

```
const str = `fnct1(param: Int, Window: String): String func2(Window: String): String function3(param: String): String`;
const regex = /[^\s(]+\(Window:\s*String\): [^(\s]+\s*/gm;
const result = str.replace(regex, '');
console.log(result);
```

This worked for me and returns `fnct1(param: Int, Window: String): String function3(param: String): String` I have hardcode `Window: String` in regex there, now I want to make it generic because type can be anything and do same which I did for `Window: String`.

It could be

```
const str = `fnct1(param: Int, Window: String): String func2(Window: Int): String function3(param: String): String`;
const str = `fnct1(param: Int, Window: String): String func2(Window: String): String function3(param: String): String`;
```

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: Replace `String` with `\w+`.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew can you answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to replace any 1 or more words after `Window:` and 0+ whitespaces.

You may use

```
/[^\s(]+\(Window:\s*\w+\):\s*[^(\s]+\s*/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RIox0d/1).

```js
var str = "fnct1(param: Int, Window: String): String func2(Window: String): String function3(param: String): String";
var regex = /[^\s(]+\(Window:\s*\w+\):\s*[^(\s]+\s*/g;
var result = str.replace(regex, '');
console.log(result);
```

**Pattern details**

- `[^\s(]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `(`
- `\(Window:` - a `(Window:` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars (ASCII letters, digits or/and `_`)
- `\):` - a `):` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[^(\s]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `(`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces